# Wired ethernet either not detected or unmanaged

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager, ethernet, wired

This is a really weird situation - I think for some reason the ethernet connection name changed from `eth0` to `eno1` when I updated ubuntu. I added those changes to the etc/nework file and changed `managed=true` in NetworkManager.conf file, but even when the network is identiified and even seems to have an IP, there is not connection. Here's the output:

```
ifconfig -a

eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:ca:b8:18:a2:65  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7200000-f7220000 

eno1:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:ca:b8:18:a2:65  
          inet addr:169.254.8.4  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7200000-f7220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3304 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3304 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:261552 (261.5 KB)  TX bytes:261552 (261.5 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:e2:44:a9:9b:f5  
          inet addr:147.252.138.6  Bcast:147.252.143.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::18e8:aa01:40ec:701/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:57219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17844 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:36931306 (36.9 MB)  TX bytes:2883308 (2.8 MB)

lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM [8086:15a2] (rev 03)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM [1028:062b]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:9ca0] (rev 03)
```

NetworkManager.conf:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

etc/interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Is the connection working?

Answer (score 0):

Is the connection working? Some time back ubuntu switched to systemd and that change moved from naming [wired connections with predictable names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/). Now the wired connections are named with something starting with `en` and wireless networks with `wl`. Your ethernet is named `eno1`.